# Join data from two tables to a single entry in 1 table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Morning all

I am hoping you can help. I have managed to achieve this in Access but seem to be failing in SQL.

**What I current have working**

In Access I have created 1 DB with 2 tables:

- DB Name 'ALL Portfolios - Total Values'
- Column Names: ID, value_date, external_ref, portfolio_name, value
- DB Name 'VAL_File_Concatenate'
- Column Names: value_date, external_ref, wrapper_name, model, value

How this works in Access is a text file is imported into VAL_File_Concatenate, then the following code is executed:

```
INSERT INTO [All Portfolios - Total Values] ( value_date, external_ref, portfolio_name, [value] ) IN 'PATH TO DB'

SELECT [Val_File_Concatenate].value_date, [Val_File_Concatenate].external_ref, [Val_File_Concatenate] [Wrapper_Name] & " - " & [Model] AS portfolio_name, Sum([Val_File_Concatenate].value) AS SumOfvalue
FROM [Val_File_Concatenate]

GROUP BY [Val_File_Concatenate].value_date, [Val_File_Concatenate].external_ref, [Wrapper_Name] & " - " & [Model]

HAVING ((([Val_File_Concatenate].value_date) Is Not Null));
```

This copies the values from VAL_File_Concatenate into the relevant fields in All_Portfolios - Total Values but amalgamates the Wrapper_Name and Model into the Portfolio_Name field in the All Portfolio - Total Values table with '-' as the separator.

For reference the VAL_File_Concatenate look like this:

```
Value_Date     External_Ref       Wrapper_Name       Model         Value
2019-03-01      Xxxxxxx/x          GIA - Cash       Liquidity      0.165
```

The Access output within the ALL Portfolio - Total Values DB is:

```
Value_Date     External_Ref      Portfolio_Name            Value
2019-03-01      Xxxxxxx/x       GIA – Cash - Liquidity     0.165
```

**What I am trying to achieve**

I have migrated the databases into SQL Server 2008, single DB with 2 tables. What I am struggling with is the part of the query that creates the Portfolio_Name in All Portfolios - Total Values via an amalgamation of the Wrapper_Name and Model fields in VAL_File_Concatenate.

Thank you in advanced for any help you can provide. I have tried various methods but I cant seem to get past the errors.

Mike

Comment: Hi Gordon, it was tagged with SQL which is the DB I am using but I have added SQL-Server-2008 and Access. Thank you for the advise

Comment: @Shattered: "SQL" is a query language, not a database product. Every relational database is a "SQL database". So what **are** you using? SQL Server or MS Access?

Comment: SQL Server, I was just expressing that I have this working in Access which is being migrated to SQL. I am using SQL 2008. All of the commands are ran within SQL 2008

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have edited for clarity, hopefully not causing further confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, the query would look more like this:

```
INSERT INTO <path to db>.[All Portfolios - Total Values] ( value_date, external_ref, portfolio_name, value )
    SELECT c.value_date, 
           c.external_ref,
           CONCAT(c.[Wrapper_Name], '-', [Model]) AS portfolio_name,
            Sum(c.value) AS SumOfvalue
    FROM Val_File_Concatenate c
    WHERE c.value_date Is Not Null
    GROUP BY c.value_date, c.external_ref, CONCAT(c.[Wrapper_Name], '-', [Model]);
```

MS Access uses non-standard syntax.  Your final query should look something like this.

Comment: Gordon, I receive the following error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'Wrapper_Name'.

Answer (score 0):

in sql server you could use  + instead of &

```
    INSERT INTO [All Portfolios - Total Values] ( value_date, external_ref, portfolio_name, [value] ) IN 'PATH TO DB'

    SELECT [Val_File_Concatenate].value_date
        , [Val_File_Concatenate].external_ref
        , [Val_File_Concatenate].[Wrapper_Name] + ' - ' + [Model] AS portfolio_name
        , Sum([Val_File_Concatenate].value) AS SumOfvalue
    FROM [Val_File_Concatenate]

    GROUP BY [Val_File_Concatenate].value_date, [Val_File_Concatenate].external_ref, [Wrapper_Name] + " - " +  [Model]

    HAVING ((([Val_File_Concatenate].value_date) Is Not Null));
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried to use the + in place of & but I receive the following error:Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near '+'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near 'Val_File_Concatenate'.

Comment: You  missed  a dot  before wrapper_name  answer updated

Comment: Well spotted, now I receive: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Invalid column name ' - '.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name ' - '.

Comment: answer  updated ..  try using single quote instead of double quote

Comment: tried that too but I receive: Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: this mean only that your insert column  is  to short  for value resulting from select that you are trying to insert ..  so check you datastruct  ..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
INSERT INTO [All Portfolios - Total Values] ( value_date, external_ref, portfolio_name, [value] ) 
SELECT 
    [Val_File_Concatenate].value_date, 
    [Val_File_Concatenate].external_ref,
    [Val_File_Concatenate].[Wrapper_Name] + ' - ' + [Val_File_Concatenate].[Model] AS portfolio_name, 
    Sum([Val_File_Concatenate].value) AS SumOfvalue
FROM 
    [Val_File_Concatenate]
WHERE 
    [Val_File_Concatenate].value_date Is Not Null
GROUP BY 
    [Val_File_Concatenate].value_date, 
    [Val_File_Concatenate].external_ref, 
    [Val_File_Concatenate].[Wrapper_Name] + ' - ' + [Val_File_Concatenate].[Model]
```